# Ubuntu user account creation within a jail

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, chroot

I have a code base the adds and removes user accounts via the shell:

```
sudo useradd #{user} --home-dir #{dir} --shell /bin/false -g usergroup
sudo usermod -G sftponly #{user}
sudo chown root:root #{dir}
sudo chmod 755 #{dir}
sudo chown #{user}:root #{dir}/homedir
echo #{user}:#{password} | sudo chpasswd
```

Unfortunately automated testing is difficult, since I need to create and cleanup test user accounts after each test run.

If the test suite fails in the middle of the run, and the cleanup fails for whatever reason, I'm left with gazillions of test user accounts and dirs on my development machine / vm.

Ideally I would like to execute my tests in a chroot jail of some sort that would allow the accounts to be created, and then I could blow away the jail on exit or fail.  Does something like this exist / is practical?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup should never fail. Even if your test fail, there is no reason for the cleanup to fail.
If your test is causing the validation script to exit prematurely, consider using an try-catch-finally around it to ensure that the cleanup code is always executed.

Alternately, you can use your tests in a VM, then reset the VM to a previously recorded clean state, however this might require a manual step or two.